# create an INDEX for a TVP in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

Can we create an Index for TVP's(Table valued Parameters) in SQL Server 2008.

please can any one give the syntax.

Thanks In advance..
Vinay K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have primary key and unique *constraints*, which will automatically have indexes backing them, but you're unable to declare any indexes explicitly for [table types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx)

---

If you think your query could benefit from further indexes, pretty well you'll have to copy the rows from your TVP into a temporary table (not table variable), on which you can define any indexes you want. But obviously that will add some additional overhead (in time and memory costs)